# Laravel 5 `Internal Server Error` (500) with Ajax form submission

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5, http-status-code-500

I'm having an issue with my `ajax` form submission in my `Laravel 5` project.  I am getting the following error in my browser console:

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I've tried many suggestions found in other posts and sites with no luck.  Here is my Ajax:

```
$.ajax({'url': './subscribe' 
    ,'data' : {
                "_token": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                ,"email" : $('#subscribe-email-input').val() 
            }
    ,'method': 'POST' 
    ,'success': function(data){
        console.log( data );
    }
    ,'error': function(data){
        console.log( 'oops', data );
    }
});
```

I have the following route defined in my `routes/web.php` file:

```
Route::post('subscribe', ['uses' => 'SubscribeController@validate', 'as' => 'subscribe.route']);
```

And the controller is pretty simple:

```
class SubscribeController extends Controller
{   
    /*
    *   Get email address from DB if exists
    *
    *   @param string email, email address to search and return data from DB
    *
    *   @returns $email
    */
    public function validate ( Request $request )
    {
        $email = addslashes($request->email) ;

        if ( $email ) 
        {           
            $email = \App\Subscribe::where('email', '=', $email)->get();

            if ( $email->isEmpty() ) 
            {
                self::executeInsertQuery ( $email );
                return json_encode( array('body' => 'You have subscribed!') );
            } else {
                return json_encode( array('body' => 'You are already subscribed!') );
            }

        }       
    }
}
```

I would post the code within `self::executeInsertQuery(...)` but I don't think its relevant considering the `subscribe` route doesn't even seem to be getting to the `validate` method.

Any suggestions or advice on how to resolve the issue would be greatly appreciated!!  Thank you in advance!

Comment: @KirkBeard this particular error doesn't appear to be causing a new log entry to be inserted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `validate` function is a predefined method in the Laravel controllers so you override it and that causes problems. try to change it to something else.

Comment: this solved my problem. Apparently, according to the error, validate is a reserved method within the base class Controller. I changed my method name from validate to verifySubscribe and everything works!!

Answer (score 2):

- First, send the form without ajax and verify if it records the sent data, then, in its ajax function, change the parameter "method": "POST" to the "type": "POST" and try again. Note: Versions prior to jquery 3.0 need to be indicated with the type or by default it will send GET.
- Second, change the name method "validate" to "validateSuscriber", since the Controller class already has a "validate" method and a conflict is created by having two equal methods.

Comment: thanks, I tried navigating to the route without Ajax (using the route in the browser) and it routed me to the Laravel `MethodNotAllowedHTTPException` page. I've also tried switching the `method` to `type` and it didn't fix the error

Comment: Do not forget to add csrf_field () in the form, if you are sending it without ajax. And also: <form action =" subscribe " method="POST">

Comment: alright, I manually posted using form action and method and removed the Ajax call.  Now I'm getting this redirected to the Laravel error page with the following message:  `Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\SubscribeController::validate(Illuminate\Http\Request $request) should be compatible with App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate(Illuminate\Http\Request $request, array $rules, array $messages = Array, array $customAttributes = Array)`

Comment: Change the name method "validate" to "validateSuscriber", because according to the error, the Controller method already has a method with it, which makes conflict

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
return response()->json([
    'body' => 'You have subscribed!'
]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#other-response-types

Comment: I updated it to use this and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Try comment all line other in function, just keep `return json` test and view log